# Restricting access to the remote on the client side. Is it possible?

Tags: git, configuration, console

Does anyone know if there is any way to restrict access to the remote on the client?

I have 2 repositories, I shoud commit to one of those (let's call it A), not the other (B), but I technically have rw access to both of them. I would like to set option in repository config file to prevent me from accidental push to B.
Is it possible?

Cheers,

Michal

Comment: why not just remove write access on the remote filesystem?

Comment: Because I don't have admin access to the machine. On top of that changing unix permissiong would change access for everybody, not just for selected individual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing the push URL?

```
git remote set-url --push origin ''
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much Sidnicious :)

Answer (score 1):

yes. Hooks are one way to add that safe guard. I would recommend using **gitolite** as it is designed for this type of repository management.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I asked a question in a very confusing way. There is no option readonly available to be set in git config. That was my wishful thinking :)